# How to delete range data if filter is present in workbook using microsoft graph api

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to delete a data of a named range by the following API- `POST /workbook/names/{name}/range/delete`. It works fine when there is no filter in workbook but it gives issues when filter is present in workbook and it gives following error message **The operation failed because it conflicts with a filtered range**. So how to handle this ? How to ignore the filter in workbook?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) they didn't mention the use of ODATA queries. But there is a workaround you can try. Just [Add a new nameditem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/nameditem-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with the range that you mention in filter give it in request body. Use the below call and specify request body according to yopur range and then delete it with your above call.

Comment: POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/Items/{itemid}/workbook/names/add`

Request body:
`{
  "name": "test5",
  "reference": "=Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4",
  "comment": "Mytest"
}`

In the reference property specify your range. It worked for me this way :)-

Comment: Did it helped you sagar?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity no, its not working for me, still the same issue,let me make it more clear - the range which i want to delete is not visible in workbook after applying filter. second thing the approach which you are suggesting will create extra named range in workbook which i don't want and i want to use limited APIs

Comment: In all the APIs I am using 'drives' like this `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveid}items/{itemid}/workbook/names/add` as using 'sites' and 'siteid' i am not able to access drive item.